# How to configure hostapd for a 5Ghz network

Tags: wifi, access-point, hostapd

https://github.com/Phoenix1747/RouteryPi contains instructions for using a Rasberry Pi as a wireless router for 2.4Ghz networks.

How can I change this to get 5Ghz? I tried to change `hw_mode` to ac, but that doesn't seem to work. Where can I get decent information on the parameters in the hostapd config file, and how do I write a good config file?

Comment: I gather my answer didn't help at all

Answer (score 14):

TL;DR

use

```
hw_mode=a
```

I see that the man pages for `hostapd` are quite useless

I found a more useful page https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Hostapd with the following example

> ### 802.11a/n/ac with WPA2-PSK and CCMP
>
> A simple but secure AP for recent hardware:
> FILE /etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf

```
interface=wlan0       # the interface used by the AP
hw_mode=a             # a simply means 5GHz
channel=0             # the channel to use, 0 means the AP will search for the channel with the least interferences 
ieee80211d=1          # limit the frequencies used to those allowed in the country
country_code=FR       # the country code
ieee80211n=1          # 802.11n support
ieee80211ac=1         # 802.11ac support
wmm_enabled=1         # QoS support

ssid=somename         # the name of the AP
auth_algs=1           # 1=wpa, 2=wep, 3=both
wpa=2                 # WPA2 only
wpa_key_mgmt=WPA-PSK 
rsn_pairwise=CCMP
wpa_passphrase=somepassword
```

with the useful comment

```
hw_mode=a             # a simply means 5GHz
```

### Please note: apparently later versions (v2.6+) of hostapd do NOT like inline comments in the config file

Comment: https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/wireless/access-point.md also contains some useful documentation on the configuration file

Comment: FYI; on hostapd v2.6  it doesn't like inline comments specifically for the hw_mode line;

    Configuration file: /etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf
    Line 5: unknown hw_mode 'a             # a = 5Ghz, g = 2.4Ghz (apparently)'
    HT (IEEE 802.11n) in 11b mode is not allowed, disabling HT capabilities
    1 errors found in configuration file '/etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf'

Comment: I used "channel=0" and never saw the AP. The service would exit after a short time with no errors.

Comment: @electron1979 - of course, this answer is almost 2.5 years old - things change

Answer (score 1):

My **hostapd.conf** in raspberry pi 3B plus with raspbian stretch:

```
interface=wlan0
ssid=pi-5G
macaddr_acl=0
ignore_broadcast_ssid=0

## 2.4G
#hw_mode=a
#channel=7


## 5G
hw_mode=a
channel=36
country_code=US
ieee80211d=1
ieee80211n=1
ieee80211ac=1
wmm_enabled=1


## wpa auth
auth_algs=1
wpa=2
wpa_passphrase=11111111
wpa_key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
wpa_pairwise=TKIP
rsn_pairwise=CCMP
```